# Facing problem when I am trying to create new component or service folder using Angular Cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Trying to create new component using Angular CLI
An unhandled exception occurred: Collection "*@angular-eslint/schematics*" cannot be resolved.

ng generate component components/search

When I pass this line my terminal line shows this error:
An unhandled exception occurred: Collection "*@angular-eslint/schematics*" cannot be resolved.

Comment: Hello, what does `npm list @angular-eslint/schematics`  display if you run it in the root of your Angular project?

Comment: It display angular-ecommerce@0.0.0 D:\Full-Stack Project\e-Commerce-project\03-frontend\angular-ecommerce
└── (empty)

Comment: Why the java and spring-boot tags?

Comment: So how I can install can you please guide me?

Comment: Hi aled sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and executing: `npm list @angular-eslint/schematics` resulted `empty`.

So just try to install that dependency as global or associated with your project using:

`npm i -g @angular-eslint/schematics`

I hope that works for you as well, regards.